# rspec getting error Failure/Error: response.should render_template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails

I am using rails 4 and rspec 3.
I have a controller which I want to test using rspec, but I am getting the following error

```
Failure/Error: response.should render_template :show
expecting <"show"> but rendering with <[]>
```

The controller_spec is like this

```
  describe "GET #show" do 
    it "renders the #show view" do 
    get :show, id: FactoryGirl.create(:product)
    response.should render_template :show
  end
 end
```

The `_show.html` partial is like this

```
    <h2><%= @product.name %></h2>
<div class="product-price"> <h3><%= number_to_currency @product.price %> </h3></div>
<div class="product-description well"><%= @product.description %> </div>
</div>

<%= link_to "Edit", edit_product_path , remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<%= link_to "Delete", product_delete_path(@product), remote: true, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
```

show.js.erb is like this

```
$("#product-details").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'show') %>")
```

and show function in product_controller is

```
 def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
       respond_to do |f|
  f.html { render nothing: true } # prevents rendering a nonexistent template file
  f.js # still renders the JavaScript template
end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

The spec is requesting HTML, and since you're rendering nothing (`render nothing: true`), the results you're getting are correct.  If you want to test rendering the .js template, preface the `get` with `xhr`:

```
xhr get :show, id: FactoryGirl.create(:product)
```